# ErrorMessage for decimal in entity-framework-core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, data-annotations, entity-framework-core-2.2

Hello im trying to customize error Message for decimal but it look like it is not work

```
   using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using Market.Models;

    namespace Market.ViewModels
    {
        public class QuettaCatViewModel
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill Amount ")] //Work fine
            public int Qentity { get; set; }
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "What ever MSg go here")]//Not Fine Getting the default Msg 
            //[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "What ever MSg go here")]
            public decimal Bedget { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tested the code , but it worked fine . Did you try it in a new project? What is the default message you get ?

Comment: @XueliChen Silly me -:) forgot _ValidationScriptsPartial ,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My bed needed   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}